# Another ridiculous abuse of "close" votes

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Here is yet another example of abuse of "close" vote pile on: [Controlling DC motor with Arduino Mega and Simple-H HV Motor Shield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24152743/controlling-dc-motor-with-arduino-mega-and-simple-h-hv-motor-shield)

Compared to the myriad other questions I see which actually *do* warrant closing, this question is excellent. The people who voted to close this question are abusing the privilege.

Want to drive people away? That is exactly the way to do it.

Comment: The community sometimes gets it wrong. Which is why the community also has the powr to reopen questions.

Comment: @slugster I would guess that we get it right more often than we get it wrong, but of course gathering concrete numbers and statistics from something like [data.se] would prove that wild guess right.

Comment: Also, have a downvote for the ranty tone `:)`.

Comment: I'm going to have to disagree - how is this question going to be useful to anyone else?  Also note that the OP completely changes his mind about what his question is in the comment thread; that's never a good sign, and the new question is too broad anyway.

Comment: Agree with Harry here (and voted to re-close the question). "Why does this function not exist?" will hardly be useful to other users in the community, assuming we manage to solve the issue from the information the questioner provides. How you could see it as "excellent" is beyond me, and I definitely don't think I'm "abusing" my privileges here.

Comment: You saw the question and probably went something like "Cool!  No idea that you can run a motor with an Arduino! I have to try this myself today, awesome idea!"  I saw the question and went "Ugh, this guy has no idea what he's doing.  He copy/pasted some code, added one line and got into trouble.  Spending 10 minutes by himself figuring this problem out would double his experience".  Raising the threshold for asking questions like this is not wrong.

Comment: @HansPassant - No Hans, I didn't and your arrogant presumptions are part of the problem on SO. But whatever– enjoy your little burst of faux superiority on the internets

Comment: @TOMATO Please keep it civil. Resorting to personal attacks is not helping to support your case.

Comment: Upvoted because the community at large is not responsible enough to use the close question voting responsibility.

Answer (score 13):

> this question is excellent

I beg to differ. If you actually read the question you'll see that nearly all information in that question is irrelevant. The question can be rewritten as follows:

> When I use
>
> ```
> int VariableMove = Serial.print();
> ```
>
> I get an error: *no matching function for call to 'HardwareSerial::print()'*
>
> How can I solve this?

A simple look at the [documentation](http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/Print) shows that this method expects either 1 or 2 parameters.

Bad question.

Comment: So you take my comment out of context and then beg to differ? What I *said* was **"Compared to the myriad other questions I see which actually do warrant closing, this question is excellent."** But whatever.

Comment: @TOMATO even with the full context, this question is not excellent at all, it's marginally better than all the other bad questions we get. On a first glance it looks excellent, but like I said it's a bad question when you remove all the background information and see what is actually being asked.

Comment: And compared to a nuclear missile, rattlesnakes aren't very dangerous. Doesn't mean that rattlesnakes aren't very dangerous...

Answer (score 6):

The code does not even compile. The reported error message indicates why. The OP has clearly not put any thought into what the error message means. That is  a good enough reason to down vote for lack of research effort.

Comment: The issue here, however, is not whether or not to downvote, but rather whether or not to close.

Answer (score 2):

The question in well..question looks to have been re-opened. And for a debugging question, while it was unclear at first what they were asking, it's much better than the 'plz snd me the codez' questions that we get.

On close votes, I can see how it may feel like to a new user that they are getting piled on (unknowingly until they find out it's closed) and that it's the end of the question forever when it's closed, but it can be edited. Maybe it should be more prominent, but that's for a feature request. The on hold modifier was a good addition that made it not seem like the end of the world for the question, and maybe it'd be a good reason to show the OP the close votes on their own question.

Comment: The OP can already see them, once he reaches 250 points. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes

Comment: @user000001 I was meaning for everyone, though. I guess I wasn't clear with that.